# Get Permalink by Slug function not working

Tags: wordpress

I hadn't realised that WordPress had added a native function for it to the Codex, but for some odd reason the page is blank. Does that mean the functionality is still coming or the page was added by mistake?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink_by_slug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's blank because it doesn't exist. If you change that function name to any random name you like you'll still see a blank page (unless of course the name you change it to is a real function).

Comment: Silly me, I thought it was the real thing when i saw it listed in Google search haha. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

function get_permalink_by_slug( $slug, $post_type = '' ) {

```
// Initialize the permalink value
$permalink = null;

// Build the arguments for WP_Query
$args = array(
    'name'          => $slug,
    'max_num_posts' => 1
);

// If the optional argument is set, add it to the arguments array
if( '' != $post_type ) {
    $args = array_merge( $args, array( 'post_type' => $post_type ) );
} // end if

// Run the query (and reset it)
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    $permalink = get_permalink( get_the_ID() );
} // end if
wp_reset_postdata();

return $permalink;
```

}